# empty query after mysql upgrade from 5.5 to 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, mysql-5.7, sql-mode

I'm working on a laravel 4.2 app that was running on a mysql 5.5. This app migrated to a new server, now running a mysql 5.7.

After the upgrade some queries are now returning empty.

I believe this as something to do with the sql_mode mysql 5.7 has introduce.

Example query

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = 'val1' and 
(SELECT count(*) FROM `table2` 
WHERE `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
   and `driver_id` = '39') >= 1 and `table1`.`id` = '86' LIMIT 1
```

This is a query that laravel eloquent produces. It returns empty. On the old mysql 5.5 it returns one line as expected.

If fixed the id from the main query it works.

```
... WHERE `table2`.`table1_id` = 86 ...
```

As I said before I believe this as something to do with the sql_mode.

Any thoughts?

Comment: " ` " is missing before table1 in where clause.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I pasted the question. That's the sql Laravel Eloquent reproduces. I just changed the table and cols names for privacy.

Comment: If I change "count(*)" to "count(`table`.`id`)" it works. Rings a bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the query, it's true that you can change the query to avoid the problem but that doesn't solve the real issue.

The solution is to disable **index_merge_intersection** in the **optimizer_switch** configuration.

It's a bug found on mysql 5.7
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79675

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases that support it, `count(*)` doesn't actually retrieve all records and count them -- instead it fetches some metadata field that just tracks the number of rows

Of course, it's reasonable to expect that, regardless of how it's implemented, the result of `count(*)` would be the same as more a complex but equivalent query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = 'val1' and 
(SELECT count(`table2`.`id`) FROM `table2` 
WHERE `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
and `driver_id` = '39') >= 1 and `table1`.`id` = '86' LIMIT 1
```

or for getting boolean try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = 'val1' and 
(SELECT 1 FROM `table2` 
WHERE `table2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id` 
and `driver_id` = '39') >= 1 and `table1`.`id` = '86' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I understand, but that's the code reproduced by Laravel Eloquent ORM.
I believe the solution is on the sql_mode configuration. I have the default by now. What do you think?